# Is there a way to record a highscore, Java

Tags: java

```Java
static int score = 0;

 public static void score(){
    score +=1;
```

OK this is the code that runs every time you score a point, my question is is there a way to record the highest score, so say you get a score of 10 i want to display that score in the top right with some text that says high score: . Also got one more question, just tried out the code and it works but is there a way to keep the numbers for the next time the game runs, whenever i close the application and then re-run it it resets the high score to 0, is there a way to keep it or not?

Comment: You are not just trying to display the highscore on a label, are you? You actually want the highscore to remain the same the next time you run your program, right?

Comment: @OP can you please go to your questions list and accept the correct answers ?

Comment: So, you 1) show invalid code (without the question being about such code); 2) ask how to record a highscore in the title; and 3) really want to display the highscore ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just maintain another variable for max score and use that for display

```
static int score = 0;
static int maxScore=0;

     public static void score(){
        score +=1;
        if(score > maxScore){
         maxScore = score;
        }
        ---
```

This `maxScore` variable gets update each time you change the score, based on the condition written.

Comment: I did not downvote you, but I think you mean `score+=1`?

Comment: @user3437460 No. What I guess is, when played did a mistake OP reducing the score by 1. But he wants to still display the max score on top :) I may be wrong as well.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Nah, "+-" is a typo I think. If OP really writes that statement, it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @Sweeper You are true. smells like pseudo code to me.

Comment: Yea it was a typo, just corrected it.

Comment: @user3437460, perhaps do some investigation first. There's only one question prior to this one that even has an answer to accept!! "this guy never"???

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils So what difference does it make for 1 or 100 questions prior to this one which can be accpeted? He already admitted he didn't even know he could accept answers. We reminded him, and now he knows. I am just stating a fact and there is nothing personal against him. But you seems to be a little over-reacted.

Comment: @user3437460, *never* doesn't apply to one instance does it? It matters because the quantity of answers doesn't mean that any answers actually helped; it's counterproductive to accept an answer just because it's there. It's pretty interesting that you see me, and not yourself, as over-reacting. Surely you know rep is given for accepting so it's not like it's not advantageous for the OP to do so.